# Does spring @Scheduled annotated methods runs on different threads?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have several methods annotated with `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=10000)`.

In the application context, I have this annotation-driven setup:

```
<task:annotation-driven />
```

The problem is, sometimes some of the method executions get delayed by seconds and even minutes.

I'm assuming that even if a method takes a while to finish executing, the other methods would still execute. So I don't understand the delay.

Is there a way to maybe lessen or even remove the delay?

Comment: please mark the answer with "SchedulingConfigurer " as a correct one.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### Spring 4.x

Code below shows the simplest possible way to configure scheduler with java config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Executor taskScheduler() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    }
    ...
```

When more control is desired, a `@Configuration` class may implement `SchedulingConfigurer`.

### Spring Boot

In Spring Boot there is a simple property to configure the thread pool size:

```
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=5
```

Comment: Since the `Executor` interface does not have `shutdown()` method, I guess it's better to use `ExecutorService` as a return type to make the bean definition correct. Or will Spring discover the actual bean type in runtime?

Comment: XML config - `<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="5"/>`

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35017579/3890673) for an example of a SchedulingConfigurer

Comment: Does not work together with Spring autoconfig: ***The bean 'taskScheduler', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/ TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource ...***

Comment: Suggesting a new answer for this for Spring Boot >= 2 (in my case v2.2.10.RELEASE) https://stackoverflow.com/a/67567777/6555159

Answer (score 73):

The [documentation about scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling) says:

> If you do not provide a pool-size attribute, the default thread pool will only have a single thread.

So if you have many scheduled tasks, you should configure the scheduler, as explained in the documentation, to have a pool with more threads, to make sure one long task doesn't delay all the other ones.

Comment: Just as an fyi: It doesn't help to provide just a link to the general docs and say that you have 'configure it'... Providing an example is infinitely more helpful. I voted for g. Demecki's answer below and not yours for this very reason... Just tips to get ahead

Comment: The quoted documentation refers to `task:scheduler` which has a `pool-size` parameter. Does this apply to the `@Scheduled` annotation which has no pool related parameters?

Comment: @DavidSoroko I believe so.

Answer (score 69):

##### If you're using Spring Boot:

There is also a property you can set in your application properties file that increases the pool size:

`spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=10`

Seems to be there since Spring Boot 2.1.0.

Comment: This is the only way to do that if spring boot version >= 2.0. Override taskScheduler() is useless

Comment: @jean As far as I can tell, this is not the case for 2.4.3. I am able to inject my own Scheduler mentioned in this post

Comment: Thank you.. is there a way to give prefix to thread?

Answer (score 50):

A method annotated with `@Scheduled` is meant to be run separately, on a different thread at a moment in time.

If you haven't provided a `TaskScheduler` in your configuration, Spring will use

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

which returns an `ScheduledExecutorService` that runs on a single thread. As such, if you have multiple `@Scheduled` methods, although they are scheduled, they each need to wait for the thread to complete executing the previous task. You might keep getting bigger and bigger delays as the the queue fills up faster than it empties out.

Make sure you configure your scheduling environment with an appropriate amount of threads.

Comment: Link to Spring documentation?

Comment: @DavidSoroko This isn't immediately obvious in Javadoc. It's easier to see it in source code. `@Scheduled` (and `@EnableScheduling`) is handled by registering a `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. This post processor uses a `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` [which defaults to that single-threaded `ScheduledExecutorService`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java#L339).

Comment: I think you are too kind - it is not in the documentation at all. As to source code - it can change from release to release.

Answer (score 15):

The [@EnableScheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) annotation provides the key information and how to resolve it:

> By default, will be searching for an associated scheduler definition:
>   either a unique TaskScheduler bean in the context, or a TaskScheduler
>   bean named "taskScheduler" otherwise; the same lookup will also be
>   performed for a ScheduledExecutorService bean. **If neither of the two
>   is resolvable, a local single-threaded default scheduler will be
>   created and used within the registrar**.
>
> When more control is desired, a @Configuration class may implement
>   SchedulingConfigurer. This allows access to the underlying
>   ScheduledTaskRegistrar instance. For example, the following example
>   demonstrates how to customize the Executor used to execute scheduled
>   tasks:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableScheduling
 public class AppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

     @Override
     public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
         taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
     }

     @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
     public Executor taskExecutor() {
         return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
     }
 }
```

(emphasis added)

Comment: Making `taskExecutor()` a bean function is pointless, since it's not going to be injected anywhere (therefore no need to keep a singleton bean in memory), but rather called directly from `configureTasks()`. Thus, `shutdown` will never be triggered, as `Executor` wont be a managed bean.

Comment: @YvesCalaci The code is from their docs, not mine.

Answer (score 11):

you can use:

```
@Bean()
public  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler  taskScheduler(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    taskScheduler.setPoolSize(2);
    return  taskScheduler;
}
```

Comment: I think its good practice to call `taskScheduler.initialize();` before returning your instance of `taskScheduler`

Comment: Did not work for me with Spring Boot v2.2.10.RELEASE: Followed another answer from @NeeruKSingh successfully: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67567777/6555159

Answer (score 0):

Using XML file add below lines..

```
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="15" />
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler" >
....
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Answer (score -2):

default spring using a single thread for schedule task. you can using @Configuration for class implements SchedulingConfigurer . referce: `https://crmepham.github.io/spring-boot-multi-thread-scheduling/`

Answer (score -2):

We need to pass our own thread pool scheduler, otherwise it will use default single threaded executor. Have added below code to fix-

```
@Bean
public Executor scheduledTaskThreadPool() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("name-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```