# What is the default scheduler pool size in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using `spring-boot` and `@Scheduled` annotation to execute some tasks.

How can I find out what the default pool size of scheduled tasks is by default in spring-boot?

Reason: the following class does not execute the jobs in parallel, but one after the other. Maybe only a single thread executor is configured by default?

```
@Service
public class ZipFileTesterAsync {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000, initialDelay = 500)
    public void run() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("import 1");
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
        System.out.println("import 1 finished");
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000, initialDelay = 1000)
    public void run2() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("import 2");
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Result: the 2nd job is executed after the first finished.

Comment: Maybe this [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support) could help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 94):

Yes, all `@Scheduled` methods share a single thread by default.
It is possible to override this behavior by defining a `@Configuration` such as this:

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulingConfigurerConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(100);
        taskScheduler.initialize();
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
    }
}
```

This example ensures that all `@Scheduled` methods share a thread pool of size 100.

Comment: is this possible to have different thead-pool for different @Scheduled annotation ?

Comment: different ThreadPoolTaskScheduler s can be created and use threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule methods.

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya No, it's not possible AFAIK. @Scheduled will always use the default task scheduler (you can look at the `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`). To be able to schedule tasks to different thread pools, just create another pools with built-in Java `java.util.concurrent.Executors`.

Comment: This methods created 100 thread even previous thread are stopped, is there any way to set a maximum nr higher but keep the running thread lower?

Answer (score 80):

The default pool size is 1, and you can set the pool size in `application.properties` since springboot2.1.0 via changing the value of `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size`.

```
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=20
```

The same task will be executed in serialized when the trigger period is shorter than the execution duration. And Spring Boot will execute different tasks in parallel with a maximum of 20 threads.

Comment: I was having trouble finding the documentation for this property at first, so here's a link to it for others who want to confirm this is correct: https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/spring-boot/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/boot-features-task-execution-scheduling.html

Comment: Official docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.task-execution-and-scheduling

Comment: This solution is more elegant, as we can change config without redeploying the application.

Comment: Note that if you or any of your dependencies define a `SchedulingConfigurer` bean, the `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size` will *not* be used anymore -- because `TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration` has a `@ConditionalOnMissingBean({ SchedulingConfigurer.class, ...`

Answer (score 5):

The default scheduler pool size in spring-boot is **only one**.

In `org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar`:

```java
    /**
     * Schedule all registered tasks against the underlying
     * {@linkplain #setTaskScheduler(TaskScheduler) task scheduler}.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void scheduleTasks() {
        if (this.taskScheduler == null) {
            this.localExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            this.taskScheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(this.localExecutor);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Using built-in capabilities and with anotated spring configuration this will be like that:

```java
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(20));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

a very simple way to do this:

```java
@Configuration
public class ScheduleConfig {
  ScheduleConfig(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler) {
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn work if you enable it in the same class with @EnableScheduling