# Spring - Scheduled Task - Graceful Shutdown

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I have a Spring-Boot application with a bean running a scheduled task at about 1 minute intervals, and this bean has a `@PreDestroy` method.

Is there a solution for allowing a task which is currently being executed to complete - or at least given some time to complete - before the life cycle reaches the pre-destroy phase?

Comment: Can you please answer this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376294/how-to-gracefully-shutdown-spring-boot-app-using-configuration-and-programatical

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need update configuration of `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`. Set true for `waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown` (method `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown`).

From documentation:

> Set whether to wait for scheduled tasks to complete on shutdown, not interrupting running tasks and executing all tasks in the queue.
>   Default is "false", shutting down immediately through interrupting ongoing tasks and clearing the queue. Switch this flag to "true" if you prefer fully completed tasks at the expense of a longer shutdown phase.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that the `@PreDestroy` is still being called prior to the task completing. I'm using a solution like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35017579/1491636 however I'm additionally setting the `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` flag to true.

Answer (score 18):

Starting from Spring Boot 2.1.0, you can use this:

```
@Bean
TaskSchedulerCustomizer taskSchedulerCustomizer() {
    return taskScheduler -> {
        taskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
        taskScheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    };
}
```

`TaskSchedulerCustomizer` will be used to modify configured `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`

Details:

1. [ExecutorConfigurationSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.html#setAwaitTerminationSeconds-int-)
2. [TaskSchedulerCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/task/TaskSchedulerCustomizer.html)

Answer (score 2):

@Matej is right. Some thing like this should do the trick

```
 @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler setSchedulerToWait(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler){
   threadPoolTaskScheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
   return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
 }
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me:

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  setSchedulerToWait defined in class path resource [at/codemonkey/shutdown/scheduler/TaskExecutorConfiguration.class]
└──<-──┘
```

Answer (score 1):

In later versions of spring boot you can also set these properties via `application.properties`. For example

```
server.shutdown=graceful
spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase=60s
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination=true
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination-period=60s
spring.task.scheduling.shutdown.await-termination=true
spring.task.scheduling.shutdown.await-termination-period=60s
```