# Java Quartz, allow only one thread per job

Tags: java, scheduling

When using Java Quartz for scheduling reccuring jobs every 2 minutes, 
Example method.

```
public void runSomething (){execute... takes 1 minute}
```

if runSomething runs into an exception it needs to handle, and it now take 3 minutes to finish, how can I make Quartz say **"I started runSomething, 2 minutes have now passed but the job is not done, do nothing, try and run the job again in two minutes"**

So Quartz can't run a thread on-top of a thread for the same job.

Comment: You can take a look on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796651/what-is-the-default-scheduler-pool-size-in-spring-boot

Comment: Thanks! I will check those threads for a solution, best regards!