# @Scheduled and scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedRate in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

What is the difference between `@Scheduled` annotation in Spring and using ScheduledExecutorService's `scheduleWithFixedDelay` method in Springboot? With the help of code, can someone demonstrate the exact usage difference and when to opt for which one?

Comment: Without knowing if the `scheduledExecutor` in your sample is managed by spring or not this is impossible to answer.

Comment: The annotation will use a shared scheduler managed by spring, whereas the other will use your own created scheduler which could lead to issues.

Comment: So is it better to replace scheduleWithFixedDelay/Rate with @Scheduled annotation?

Comment: @JerinDJoy Depends on your needs, really :-) `@Scheduled` gives you a nice abstraction, but you still should configure underlying executor if you want to have more control. See this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796651/what-is-the-default-scheduler-pool-size-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler . The `@Scheduled` is a generic implementation, which you can extend and configure for your needs. While the scheduleWithFixedDelay is a specific implementation that you can directly use. Ideally, it is fine to use either of them, but if your functionality is not supposed to change, it is better to use the implementation (I mean `scheduleWithFixedDelay`)

Comment: So say if an interrupted exception or any other exception occurs, the ScheduledExecutorService will stop. What about the @Scheduled annotated method? Since it is managed by Spring, will Spring spawn it again?

Comment: scheduleWithFixedDelay is triggered from `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` class. While `Scheduled` is an interface, and the action is performed by `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. Invocation of this is triggered by an implementation of TaskScheduler interface. While ThreadPoolTaskScheduler is also an implementation of the TaskScheduler interface, the behavior is consistent. Since these classes deal with async operations, exceptions related to concurrency can occur at any time, so we have to make sure the logic is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

@Scheduled without a cron expression, fixeddelay or fixedrate is nothing. How can it know the interval, if not specified?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html

fixedDelay ensures that there is always n seconds duration

> if first invocation is at 9:00:00 and fixedDelay = 10minutes, process
> takes 15 seconds to complete, then next cycle start = 09:10:15