# Multiple Invocations of @Scheduled annotated method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, executorservice

Following this guide, I was able to set up a scheduled task in springboot and have it run at periodic intervals.

[Getting Started - Scheduled Tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Simple enough and works perfectly. Now let's say that what I'm doing inside the "scheduled task" method is reading from an Amazon SQS and processing the messages. My queue can handle multiple consumers concurrently, so I'd like to run the code inside my method on multiple threads at the same time if possible.

A couple more things:

1. By default, scheduler has a thread pool of size 1.
2. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993464/does-spring-scheduled-annotated-methods-runs-on-different-threads) I can configure the scheduler to run with a thread pool of size > 1.

But the multi-thread scheduler approach comes in more handy when I have multiple methods annotated with the @Scheduled annotation. So that multiple methods don't have to wait on a single thread to run.

The question I have is, how can I invoke the same method (annotated with @Scheduled) with multiple threads at a set interval? After reading through the documentation, I'm suspecting that this may not be provided out of the box.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you using the @Schedule to read from SQS instead of use JMS approach? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-java-message-service-jms-client.html

Comment: Maybe the AWS detail is not very relevant here. But I'm currently using the AWS SDK as a test. Let's say the task I am performing inside the method is something entirely different from reading AWS, but I want to invoke the same method with multiple threads at every fixed interval/delay.

Comment: I would never put the "business logic" inside the @ Scheduled method. Instead of, I would use another @ Component, with a method with the @ Async annotation, so when you scheduled method is invoked by the scheduler, another thread assumes the execution and your scheduled method is free to be called again. Check here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support