# Adding scheduler for @Scheduled annotation in spring without using xml annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have several methods with the annotation `@Scheduled`. For each annotation or a group of them I want a different scheduler to be used. For example:
Group A has 3 methods with `@Scheduled` annotation which need to use Scheduler X.
Group B has 5 methods with `@Scheduled` annotation which need to use Scheduler Y.

From what I have read in [Does spring @Scheduled annotated methods runs on different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993464/does-spring-scheduled-annotated-methods-runs-on-different-threads), if the scheduler is not specified then only one of those methods will run at a time.

I know how this connection can be done using xml-based annotation.  But is there a way that this can be done using Java-based annotation only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using java config. But not using an annotation attributes.

You could have a look at the [Spring API doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) for some extended example.

For example:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableScheduling
 public class AppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

     @Override
     public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
         taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskScheduler());
     }

     @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
     public Executor taskScheduler() {
         return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(42);
     }

 }
```

`@Scheduled` group is not yet supported. See this [open issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14218).

If you want use more than one scheduler you have to create and configure them programmatically. For example:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableScheduling
 public class AppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

     [...]

     @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown", name = "taskSchedulerA")
     public Executor taskSchedulerA() {
         return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(42);
     }
     @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown", name = "taskSchedulerB")
     public Executor taskSchedulerA() {
         return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(42);
     }
 }


 @Service
 public class MyService {
      @Autowired @Qualifier("taskSchedulerA")
      private Executor taskSchedulerA; 
      @Autowired @Qualifier("taskSchedulerB")
      private Executor taskSchedulerB; 

      @PostConstruct
      public void schedule(){
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(42).schedule(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            functionOfGroupA();
          }
    } , ..);

      }
 }
```

Comment: I did not quite follow. So how can we use two different schedulers using this?

Comment: you should create and use programmatically two scheduler