# Unable to consume a rest api using resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have this api i am trying to consume and this is the link `https://www.live-rates.com/api/price?key=123456&rate=EUR_USD`

I have tried  this in my controller

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/start" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String start() { 
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String quote = restTemplate.getForObject("https://www.live-rates.com/api/price?key=123456&rate=EUR_USD", String.class);
        return quote.toString();
    }
```

and this in my scheduling program

```
package com.boilerplate.components;


import java.util.Date;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;

import com.boilerplate.services.MessageListenerService;
import java.util.Random;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Repository
@Transactional
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class Scheduler {
//Database read and update and delete
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageListenerService.class);

    @Autowired 
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Async
    @Scheduled(cron="*/60 * * * * *")
    public void doSomething(){

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String quote = restTemplate.getForObject("https://www.live-rates.com/api/price?key=123456&rate=EUR_USD", String.class);
        LOGGER.info(quote.toString());

  }


    }
```

and they all fail to get the exchange rate.

I get this error when using the scheduler

> SEVERE: Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void
>   com.boilerplate.components.Scheduler.doSomething()'.
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
>           at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264)
>           at com.boilerplate.components.Scheduler.doSomething(Scheduler.java:53)
>           at com.boilerplate.components.Scheduler$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$17802b05.invoke()
>           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

and this when using the controller

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /boilerplate/start. Reason:
>
> ```
> Server Error
> ```
>
> Caused by:
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)

I have tried consuming other json apis like `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` and i can get the json without any problem.

Why cant i get the exchange rate using the rest template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try adding below code. You are trying to invoke with HTTPS.

`CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
                .build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        String quote = restTemplate.getForObject("https://www.live-rates.com/api/price?key=123456&rate=EUR_USD",
                String.class);`

Comment: This has worked for me. I had to add apache httpclient library to my dependencies - [link to maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `@Async` with your `@Scheduled` annotation. The scheduler will run on it's own thread anyways. Of course, one or more running scheduler will run sequentially, but that can be change. For your case though, regarding the documentation, it seems that, you might have to provide your restTemplate via dependency injection. So, `@Autowire` could do the trick. [Documentation, section 27.4.2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks).

> Notice that the methods to be scheduled must have void returns and
>   must not expect any arguments. If the method needs to interact with
>   other objects from the Application Context, then those would typically
>   have been provided through dependency injection.

So, removing the `@Async` and adding the dependency injection of `restTemplate` could do the trick.

In case you need to know how to run multiple schedulers in different threads, you could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173390/running-each-spring-scheduler-in-its-own-thread).

Comment: Autowiring restTemplate make the program freeze at a certain point, teh application cannot now finish starting up.

Comment: Freezes without any error? You did remove the Async annotation? Also try removing the other Autowired dependencies that you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to original question, but if the variable 'quote' is already of type 'String' why do you need to call the method 'toString()' on it?

Comment: Should have been `Response response = restTemplate.getForObject()...`