# Spring Boot:How can we implement multiple @Scheduled tasks with each having its own thread pool?

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, threadpool, spring-scheduled

I want to implement multiple @Scheduled(with fixed delay) tasks, each with their own thread pools.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "30000")
public void createOrderSchedule() {
    //create 10 orders concurrently; wait for all to be finished
    createOrder(10);
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "30000")
public void processOrderSchedule() {
    //process 10 orders concurrently; wait for all to be finished
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "30000")
public void notifySchedule() {
    //send notification for 10 orders concurrently; wait for all to be finished
}
```

I managed to create different `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for every scheduler as below:

```
@Bean("orderPool")
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor createOrderTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(5);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    pool.setThreadNamePrefix("order-thread-pool-");
    pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    return pool;
}

..
```

I provided `@Async` over each task.

```
@Async("orderPool")
public void createOrder(Integer noOforders) {..}
```

and a task scheduler config

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(3);
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

I used `CompletableFuture.allOf(..).join();` to wait for each task to complete, but it blocks every other `@Scheduled` tasks.

To sum up, I want to achieve following:

1. Each `@Scheduled` tasks should run independently without blocking other `@Scheduled` tasks.
2. Each `@Scheduled` tasks should have it's own thread pool, so that it can run multiple sub tasks(say 10) concurrently.
3. Each `@Scheduled` tasks must wait for each trigger to complete without getting invoked again.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running each Spring Scheduler in its own thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173390/running-each-spring-scheduler-in-its-own-thread)

Comment: no, but I hv solved it, soon I'll post my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being at it for almost 18 hours straight, I was able to achieve what I asked in above question. Apologies for being this late.

So stream APIs provides interfaces like `IntStream`, etc to stream the elements in parallel. This led me to create `n` orders parallely. (At the same time, process `k` orders parallely, in different scheduler. And so on.)

```
IntStream.range(0, inputIds.size())
        .parallel().forEach(index -> createOrder(inputIds.get(index)));
```

This was just as this simple. 1 use-case solved. Now I wanted this scheduler to have it's own pool. Found out that `IntStream.parallel()` uses `ForkJoinPool`, which is the successor of our own `ExecutorService` and to my surprise, spring provides a preconfigured factory bean for `ForkJoinPool`, ie, `ForkJoinPoolFactoryBean`. So I created a bean named `createOrderExecutor`.

```
@Bean("createOrderExecutor")
public ForkJoinPoolFactoryBean createOrderExecutor() {
    ForkJoinPoolFactoryBean createOrderPoolFactoryBean = new ForkJoinPoolFactoryBean();
    createOrderPoolFactoryBean.setParallelism(10);
    createOrderPoolFactoryBean.setAsyncMode(true);
    createOrderPoolFactoryBean.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(null);
    createOrderPoolFactoryBean.setThreadFactory(p -> {
        final ForkJoinWorkerThread worker = ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(p);
        worker.setName("create-order-pool-" + worker.getPoolIndex());
        return worker;
    });
    return createOrderPoolFactoryBean;
}
```

I autowired this bean in my scheduler class, and submitted all orders simultaneously, as shown below.

```
createOrderExecutor.getObject().submit(() -> IntStream.range(0, inputIds.size())
                .parallel().forEach(index -> createOrder(inputIds.get(index))));
```

There. 2nd use-case solved. Now this won't wait for all the parallel tasks to finish, it will just trigger them async-ly. Now, `ForkJoinTask`(that `submit()` returns) provides a `get()` method, which waits for the computation to complete & returns the result. (But I don't need result, I would rather surround them with `try-catch`. And, I'll just wait for the completion.)

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "5000")
public void createOrderScheduler() {
        createOrderExecutor.getObject().submit(() -> IntStream.range(0, inputIds.size())
                .parallel().forEach(index -> createOrder(inputIds.get(index)))).get();
}
```

This solved my last use-case. I did this for all my schedulers in the application.

Believe me, I tried with almost all the implementations of `CompletableFuture` available online, but wasn't able to achieve all this.