# spring-boot @scheduled not running in different threads?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I am configuring a scheduled task to run in different threads.
Here is the configuration code

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("my-sched-pool-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
}
```

Here is the code that uses it

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "2000" )
    public void testaMethod() {

         log.debug("here is the message");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I am sleeping the thread for 10s with fixedRate of 2s. so I expect to see different threads in the log
but I see only one

logs are here

```
{"thread":"my-sched-pool-1","level":"DEBUG","description":"here is the message"}
{"thread":"my-sched-pool-1","level":"DEBUG","description":"here is the message"}
{"thread":"my-sched-pool-1","level":"DEBUG","description":"here is the message"}
{"thread":"my-sched-pool-1","level":"DEBUG","description":"here is the message"}
```

Comment: Did you read this thread: [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21994185/1009448)

Comment: @Edmond: yes, what are you referring to? I have configured the default pool size above

Comment: I was not able to reproduce exactly but I think you may have found a bug. `fixedRate` should invoke the method every 2s but in my pc was taking 10s, but I did got different threads used.

Answer (score 9):

`@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "2000" )` does not gurantee `testaMethod` be executed every 2 seconds, if the time cost is more than 2s, such as `Thread.sleep(10000)`, the new task will be put in a queue. Only when the old one has been executed, the scheduler will fetch the new task from queue and execute it. Since the new task is now the only task in the scheduler, it could be run without creating a new `Thread`.

**To solve this problem, you can combile [@Async and @Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)**

SchedulerConfig

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(poolScheduler());
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler poolScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("poolScheduler");
        scheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        return scheduler;
    }

}
```

SchedulerTask

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SchedulerTask {

    @Autowired
    private AsyncTask asyncTask;

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "2000" )
    public void testaMethod() {
        asyncTask.asyncMethod();
    }
}
```

AsyncTask

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncTask {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AsyncTask.class);

    @Async
    public void asyncMethod() {
        log.debug("here is the message");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Test results**

```
11:20:54.682 [poolScheduler1] DEBUG com.test.AsyncTask - here is the message
11:20:56.668 [poolScheduler3] DEBUG com.test.AsyncTask - here is the message
11:20:58.668 [poolScheduler2] DEBUG com.test.AsyncTask - here is the message
11:21:00.669 [poolScheduler6] DEBUG com.test.AsyncTask - here is the message
11:21:02.669 [poolScheduler7] DEBUG com.test.AsyncTask - here is the message
11:21:04.669 [poolScheduler4] DEBUG com.test.AsyncTask - here is the message
```

Comment: you are using two three different methods. can you emulate in a single method using multiple threads? in fact, with three methods, you dont even have to do `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: Hi, the first paragraph explained why using one method with Thread.sleep(10000) may not creating multiple threads.

Comment: Breifly, when use one method with Thread.sleep(10000) , the `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)` will ignored, the period will be 10 seconds, and the threads may be reused.

Comment: I understood what you meant. but I am trying to emulate multiple threads in one method. what you suggested is multiple methods and they will use different threads. you dont have to sleep in each of these three methods.

Comment: I have tried with both async and scheduled and got it work.  just wondering if I can get to work only with @scheduled. Thanks for digging into this though. +1

Comment: ok. According to the docs, it seems not likely to get a  asynchronous task with only @scheduled. I marked the question and see any other solution.