# @Scheduled and @Async are sharing same threadpool in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, threadpoolexecutor, spring-scheduled, spring-async

I have configured two different thread pools, one for `@Scheduled` and other for `@Async`. However, I notice that the thread-pool for `@Async` is not being used.

Here is the Scheduler configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("my-sched-pool-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
}
```

Here is the Configuration for Async

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {

 @Bean(name = "asyncTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(15);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("my-async-pool-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Here is how I invoke them

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "2000" )
    public void schedule() {
      log.debug("here is the message from schedule");
      asyncMethod();
    }

@Async("asyncTaskExecutor")
public void asyncMethod(){
  log.info("here is the message from async");
}
```

Here are the logs

```
{"thread":"my-sched-pool-1","level":"DEBUG","description":"here is the message from schedule"}
{"thread":"my-sched-pool-1","level":"INFO","description":"here is the message from async"}
```

As you can notice, both logs are having same pool of that scheduler. but I expect to see the second one to come from async

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you call `@Async` methods from the same `class` they are declared you are effectively bypassing Spring's proxy mechanism and that is why your example is not working. Try calling the method from a separate `class` annotated with `@Service` or any of the other `@Component` types.

```
@Service
SomeScheduledClass {

  private final SomeAsyncClass someAsyncClass;

  public SomeScheduledClass(SomeAsyncClass someAsyncClass) {
    this.someAsyncClass = someAsyncClass;
  }

  @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "2000" )
  public void schedule() {
    log.debug("here is the message from schedule");
    someAsyncClass.asyncMethod();
  }
}

@Service
SomeAsyncClass {
  @Async("asyncTaskExecutor")
  public void asyncMethod(){
    log.info("here is the message from async");
  }
}
```

Comment: huh. I forgot that proxy thing. I am trying now

Comment: worked!. you wanna give this a shot ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233445/spring-boot-scheduled-not-running-in-different-threads?noredirect=1#comment83449470_48233445