# Long running spring scheduled task

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a Spring scheduled task defined in context.xml file which run every minute.
the task calls a postgres stored procedure. 
The Stored procedure run time can last more than a minute. 
Will the spring framework call the same scheduler if the current run did not finish ? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spring framework,one scheduled task only executed by one thread,if the execute time longer than the interval period，the task will be delayed。Here is a simple example:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/3 * * * * *")
public void work() {
    log.info("begin to do some work,current thread is {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error(e.toString());
    }
}
```

I create a scheduled task,expected execution sequence: 0 3 6 9 ...,but the task need more time,so the execution sequence:0 6 12 18 ...

In spring all task will be executed by on thread(default),in order to reduce interference between tasks,we can support a thread pool to execute shceduled tasks like this:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setPoolSize(20);
    return scheduler;
}
```

Other question about scheduled task in spring:[Does spring @Scheduled annotated methods runs on different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993464/does-spring-scheduled-annotated-methods-runs-on-different-threads)